# Expected 'trust-anchor' error message when install Bind DNS Server on Centos 5.9

Tags: linux, dns, bind, centos5

I'm about installing DNS Server on VPS with Centos 5.9 operating system, I have followed step by step from this website https://www.digitalocean.com/community/articles/how-to-install-the-bind-dns-server-on-centos-6

when i try to restart the service with:

```
    service named restart
```

there is following error:

```
Stopping named: [ OK ] 
Starting named: 
Error in named configuration:

/etc/named.conf:23: unknown option 'dnssec-validation' 
/etc/named.conf:24: expected 'trust-anchor' near ';'
```

any solution to solve this problem? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

finally i remove these lines:

```
dnssec-validation yes;
dnssec-lookaside auto;
```

and replace it with:

```
dnssec-lookaside . trust-anchor dlv.isc.org.;
```